# Applying SFINAE pattern with universal reference

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I've got the following code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <future>

class Runner {
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual ~Runner() {
    }
};

class Command: public Runner {
public:
    Command() {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void run() {
    }
};

#define EXTEND(T, F) , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<F, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value, typename std::decay<T>::type>::type
#define NOT_EXTEND(T, F) , typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<F, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value, typename std::decay<T>::type>::type

class Executor {
private:
    std::queue<std::function<void(void)> > q;
public:
    template<class T EXTEND(T, Runner)>
    void push(T&& toBepushed) {
        q.push(
                std::bind(&std::decay<T>::type::run,
                        std::forward<T>(toBepushed)));
    }
    template<typename T NOT_EXTEND(T, Runner)>
    void push(T&& toBepushed) {
        q.push(std::forward<T>(toBepushed));
    }
    void perform() {
        std::function<void(void)>&& f = std::move(q.front());
        f();
    }
};

int main() {
    Executor b;
    Command c;
    b.push(c);
    b.perform();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile I've got the following error:

> g++ -std=c++0x -O2 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP
>   -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp" ../main.cpp:45:7: error: ‘template void Bar::push(T&&)’ cannot be
>   overloaded   void push(T&& toBepushed) {
>          ^~~~ ../main.cpp:39:7: error: with ‘template void Bar::push(T&&)’   void push(T&& toBepushed) {
>          ^~~~ make: *** [subdir.mk:20: main.o] Error 1

I'm trying to apply SFINAE in order to have the push method applied according to the type used. How to solve?

Comment: what do you use sfinae and not just use conditional in you template? seems you want one or the other, thus should work, imho?

Comment: I want the flexiblity to use an instance of Runner or a lambda

Comment: You don't need to use macros: template alias are *equivalent to their definition*... This is how it is said in the standard. It means substitution occurs in the context where is named the alias. So they realy behave as a kind of macro. Just try it : `template <class T,class R> using extend = typename std::enable...`

Comment: no idea what you mean, I used a macro just to have a short form

Comment: That: https://godbolt.org/z/Z41JRE This is much cleaner no?

Comment: And more cleaner:https://godbolt.org/z/YKssFN, constraint applied to return type is better, because it is not hackable.

Comment: Last but not least, that demonstrates what are template alias:https://godbolt.org/z/d0Hkue

Comment: oh nice, I didn't know it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default argument is not part of the template parameter list, thus your two `push` have identical template parameter list, which leads a redeclaration.

This is a typical drawback of `typename = std::enable_if_t<...>` approach. Instead, you should use `std::enable_if_t<..., int> = 0` approach.

Change to this:

```
#define EXTEND(T, F) , typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<F, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value, int>::type = 0
#define NOT_EXTEND(T, F) , typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<F, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value, int>::type = 0
```