# Conditional function behavior based on pointer-ness of template type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I'm trying to come up with a member function for a template class that:

- does something in case the template type is a pointer
- does nothing for non-pointers

Not sure if SFINAE applies to this, since I need both versions as I call them in the class itself. Please note I'm limited to C++11.

```
template < typename T_ = T, typename = std::enable_if_t <!std::is_pointer<T_>{} > >
void SomeFunction()
{
    // Do nothing
}
template < typename T_ = T, typename = std::enable_if_t < std::is_pointer<T_>{} > >
void SomeFunction()
{
    // Do sth
}
```

Compiler complains that *error C2535: member function already defined or declared*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351945/applying-sfinae-pattern-with-universal-reference/53352035#53352035

Comment: Another compilcated SFINAE that can be made very trivial with C++17 `if constexpr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that default template arguments are not the part of [function template signature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading). The two `SomeFunction`s are considered as identical and then causes redeclaration error.

> Two function templates are considered equivalent if
>
> - they are declared in the same scope
> - they have the same name
> - they have identical template parameter lists
> - the expressions involving template parameters in their return types and parameter lists are equivalent

You can use them in return types, e.g. (for C++11)

```
template <typename T_ = T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T_>::value>::type SomeFunction()
{
    // Do nothing
}
template <typename T_ = T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T_>::value>::type SomeFunction()
{
    // Do sth
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IA0esqFrvcYuBHP8)

Or use them in non-type template parameter list, e.g. (for C++11)

```
template < typename T_ = T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T_>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void SomeFunction()
{
    // Do nothing
    std::cout << "Do nothing\n";
}
template < typename T_ = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T_>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void SomeFunction()
{
    // Do sth
    std::cout << "Do sth\n";
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FU12Ezha20y1YIgU)

Comment: Excellent! A little cleaner version would be `template < typename T_ = T, typename std::enable_if_t < !std::is_pointer<T_>{} >* = nullptr>`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the two function template declaration are *equivalent*, so the compiler consider that your code contain 2 function definitions for a unique function.

Function template equivalence is described in [[temp.over.link]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#6) and [[temp.over.link]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#7).

In your specific case, the problem is that this *equivalence* does not take into account of the default template argument.

If you add a defaulted template parameter, the two functions will not be equivalent:

```
   template < typename T_ = T
            , typename = std::enable_if_t <!std::is_pointer<T_>{} > >
    void SomeFunction()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
    template < typename T_ = T
             , class=void
             , typename = std::enable_if_t < std::is_pointer<T_>{} > >
    void SomeFunction()
    {
        // Do sth
    }
```